# knockout js jquery-mobile collapsible-set doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

Hi I hope you can help me this problems driving me up the wall!

I have a collapsible-set structure like the following:

```
    <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-bind="foreach: thisTemplateColumnList">
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3 data-bind ="text: Name"></h3>
            <p>I'm the collapsible set content for section 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It displays the header correctly (the column Name) but the collapsible part doesn't work and I see the 

I'm the collapsible set content for section 1

 as well which I shouldn't see until the collapsible is expanded.

I've successfully tried using jquery-mobile collapsible in a static layout and that works just fine. Why doesn't the **foreach:** version work?

Thanks in advance.
Steve

Comment: When does jQuery-mobile evaluate the DOM to do its UI magic.  As KO is dynamically updating the UI you might need to get jQuery-mobile to reparse

Comment: So how do I get jQuery-mobile to reparse?

Comment: I haven't used the plugin and I can't find anything in the docs, but looking at the source the following might help: line 5318 $.mobile.collapsible.prototype.enhanceWithin( e.target ).  Add an afterRender option to the foreach and invoke this function directly

Answer (score 0):

I had also encountered this problem, and it got fixed by changing the markup to use script template. so in your case, change the markup to:

```
<script type="text/html" id="template-column-list">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3 data-bind ="text: Name"></h3>
        <p>I'm the collapsible set content for section 1</p>
    </div>
</script>

<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-bind="template: { name: 'template-column-list', foreach: thisTemplateColumnList}">

</div>
```

Later after applying binding, you probably need to call this code:

```
$('[data-role="collapsible-set"]').trigger('create');
```